# Kubernetes NetworkPolicy Need select all pods except certain pods with labels

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

Is there a way to apply a NetworkPolicy to all Pods except certain pods with label?

Example :

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: standard-allow-ingress
spec:
  policyTypes:
    - Ingress
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: foo
  ingress:
    - from:
        - podSelector: {}
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 0.0.0.0/0
```

So this Network Policy is applied only to Pods which has label app:foo but I want to apply this NetworkPolicy to all Pods except app:foo label

Answer (score 0):

As per the [network policy reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.26/#networkpolicy-v1-networking-k8s-io), this cannot be done. However, you can have two network policies working together, the first policy would deny all traffic, then you can have rules to allow the traffic you require.

By default, the traffic is allowed unless you specify otherwise.